# Window.opener with child window navigate in same window not working

Tags: javascript, fckeditor, window.opener

I have scenario like P is parent page and from that page one child page is being open using window.open(C) where C is child page. Now I have to navigate in same child window. Let's call that page as C1.

I found when I try to access one button of page P from page C1, it gave me not found.
My syntaxt is like (in page C1),

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('xyz');
```

Is there any way using which I can identify the page I am getting in window.opener is same page what I am looking for?

Comment: Are the parent and child in the same domain?

Comment: what is `C1`? an iFrame inside the page `C`?

Comment: @epascarello yes it is in same domain

Comment: @m.abbas there is no iframe in child window.

Comment: @m.abbas C1 is navigated page from C (in child window) - I mean navigation also happens in child window.

Comment: ok i see! When you navigate to a new page (different host) other than `C`, the browser,  for **secutiry reasons**, will set the `window.opener` property to `null` thats why `window.opener.document.getElementById('xyz');` doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:
`Is there any way using which I can identify the page I am getting in window.opener is same page what I am looking for?`

Just an idea: generate some random value before opening the new window and store it in the parent window, write this value to the new window and cross-reference.

Update:
You can share data between parent and child browser windows at some scenarios as shown below:

`window.opener.functioname(arg1,arg2,..)`
- to send data to the parent window from child window

`winobj.functioname(arg1,arg2,..)`
- to send data to the child window from parent window using the window handle got from window.open()

See for a lot more info on [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice).

Good luck!

Comment: To chekck `Is there any way using which I can identify the page I am getting in window.opener is same page what I am looking for?` I used 
window.opener.print(); and found it's accessing parent page only from which window.open(C) is called.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) on my parent page and child page opened from that editor only. So I have to have use `window.opener.parent.my_function();`

Thanks a lot to all who helped me.